# Function Browsing In Spacemacs And CIDER

Tags: clojure, spacemacs, cider

In [Spacemacs](http://spacemacs.org/), with an active [CIDER](https://cider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) REPL, is there a way to browse *and jump to* the functions in the current `clojure-mode` buffer?

I have tried `cider-browse-ns`. However, that appears to just display the functions and variables in the current namespace, along with their docstrings. The list cannot be used to jump directly to the function/var in the source code. I am also aware that `g d` will jump directly to the definition of the function under point. So the pieces of what I am looking for seem to all be available, I just cannot find how to wire them together.

An analogy to what I am looking for is IntelliJ's `Structure` sidebar.

It would be awesome if IntelliJ's `Navigate -> Symbol` functionality was possible as well. Searching for the function name, using `/`, comes pretty close (albeit without the handy fuzzy matching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would `SPC s j` (help-jump-in-buffer) be what you search ?

Comment: Presumably that's "helm". Is there any way to configure it so that it doesn't always present itself from the top of the list but highlight and have the cursor from which position you are already at?

Answer (score 1):

Pressing backslash then S `\s` will help you jump to the definition.

Here is [the list of the available commands](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/blob/master/cider-browse-ns.el#L53) in `browse-ns`. But since Spacemacs puts you in evil-mode by default, you should precede each command by a `\` which [temporarily disables it](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil#toc10).